# Maximo 7.6 Change status dialog box (Notification E-mail field) default blank

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere, tivoli

Seeking for guidance, in Maximo 7.6 the change status dialog box has a field (toemailaddr) Label: Notification E-mail for work Order change status. See the picture below.

What I am seeking guidance on is how do I edit that field to where I make it to default blank over populating the user logged in e-mail by default? Is this even possible?

I have looked in the change status dialog on WOTRACK as well extracted Library.XML and did not find a way to change from it filling in by default with users e-mail to just remaining blank.

I apologize in advance if it shows to be tagged incorrectly.

[`Picture of what I am looking to change to show blank`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oafBy.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's the Maximo "psdi.app.workorder.virtual.WOChangeStatus" MBO class that is defaulting that value in.

If the presentation-level default values run after the MBO add() code, then a simple presentation "Default Value" control should allow you to override that.

If that doesn't work then you can try an automation script. It would need to be against the WOCHANGESTATUS object and on the "add" action. If that runs after the Java code then you could grab that field (toEmailAddr) and set it back to an empty string. I assume the screen would still update with that change.

I have not looked at the code for any downstream effects clearing this field might have. It could be that Maximo is coded to *always* send out that email and if the email address is empty it would likely error at that point.

Answer (score 0):

create an automation script named WOCHANGESTATUS.NEW

(automation scripts that are named after a mbo followed by .NEW are executed when a new instance of a MBO is created, they can be used to initialize column values. )

put a single line in the script.
mbo.setValueNull("TOEMAILADDR")

mark script active and save it